# Ssl reverse proxy from IIS to Node on same server. Ok to redirect internally over http?

Tags: ssl, iis-7, node.js

I've got IIS exposed to the internet. On the same server I've got a NodeJS-app running (port 8080). I need to expose the node app over SSL to the internet.

Is it possible to just switch from Https -> http when doing the reverse proxy call from IIS -> Node?

This would make my life easier because I don't need to support https directly on Node. Hence, I'd only need to install a SSL-cert on the IIS-server.

So in short my plan is:

`ssl (443) -> IIS ->  - (https -> http) -> NodeJS (8080)`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect your HTTP requests to the loopback address `127.0.0.1:8080` it can be considered pretty secure as it will not pass through the network at all (TCP/IP stack wont send it to the physical network). Just make sure you only expose the IIS SSL port to the external network (blocking 8080 with the firewall).